# Javascript Canvas – How Can We Draw Lines (shapes) in Zoomed in and keep them in Appropriate Size When Zooming Out/In?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I’m showing an image in a canvas, and reproducing the zoom-in effect with setTransform(), then I draw some lines…The problem is when I’m zooming out the drawings are still big (exactly like they were in the zoom mode).
This is the illustration of the problem:

[image: zoom]

The line shouldn’t be in the 100% width of canvas when we are zooming out :(
Should I use 2 canvases as layers (one for background and the other one for drawings)?
How should I coordinate the size (length & height) of lines, shapes, etc. with all zoom ins and outs?
I’d appreciate it if someone shed some light on this problem…

Comment: Can you show us your current code?

Comment: How do you zoom ? context.scale, css, some hand-made drawing, a lib ?